# Zend Action Helpers not loading through Action HelperBroker

Tags: php, zend-framework

In my module bootstrap:

```
<?php

class Api_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAllowedMethods()
    {
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $front->setParam('api_allowedMethods', array('POST'));
    }

    protected function _initActionHelperBrokers()
    {
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/api/controllers/helpers', 'Api_Controller_Action_Helper_');

        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(new Api_Controller_Action_Helper_Model());
    }
}
```

There is a `Api_Controller_Action_Helper_Model` at `/var/www/project/application/modules/api/controller/helpers/Model.php`

But I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Api_Controller_Action_Helper_Model' not found in /var/www/accounts.amh.localhost/application/modules/api/Bootstrap.php on line 15
```

As far as I can tell from the API and http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/using-action-helpers-in-zend-framework/ this should work.

I'm pretty sure this isn't a bootstrapping issue like I have had before, as I am specifically add the path/prefix right before trying to add the helper.

What else might I have missed?

Comment: just out of curiosity, in which line of your bootstrap is the _initActionHelperBrokers method ?

Comment: hi - I've added the whole module bootstrap

Comment: try Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper('Model'); you have a problem with autoloaders. this is why "new Api_Controller_Action_Helper_Model()" is not working. But when you only give the name of the helper, ZF should use the helper path to find it.

Comment: `Argument 1 passed to Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper() must be an instance of Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract, string given, called in /var/www/accounts.amh.localhost/application/modules/api/Bootstrap.php on line 14` - the API says nothing about being able to pass a string to this method...

Comment: try to rename the class only to "Api_Controller_Helper_Model()" so you could be sparing adding an own resourcetype loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the module autoloader does not know about controller action helper resources.

Try something like this in your module bootstrap

```
protected function _initResourceLoader()
{
    $resourceLoader = $this->getResourceLoader();

    $resourceLoader->addResourceType('actionhelper',
            'controllers/helpers', 'Controller_Action_Helper');
}
```

All that being said, as your helper has an empty constructor, you could omit the `addHelper()` line and just let the broker automatically create it when requested in your controllers, eg

```
$helper = $this->getHelper('Model');
```

Comment: Thanks - I had tried following and modifying http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html to get resource autoloaders working - but I was passing the full path and full prefix instead of like what you posted.